# Unity 5 Multiplayer prefab not showing for client

Tags: c#, multiplayer, unity-game-engine

I have a multiplayer scene in which the player spawns a prefab at a given time. The problem I am having is that the prefab is only showing on the client that spawns it.

```
void Spawn()
{
    GameObject slice = (GameObject)Instantiate (slice1Prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Rigidbody rb = slice.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb.velocity = lastVelocity;
    NetworkServer.Spawn (slice);
}
```

This is what I have, I have tried dozens of variations and other ideas but am completely stuck at this point. How do I go about properly instantiating a prefab so that all the clients including the host can see it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, I think your question would be better directed to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Are you registering the prefab on your Network Manager?
Also does the prefab you are instantiating have a NetworkIdentity component attached to it?

A code snippet of the full class might help in finding why this isnt working for you.